# How to access variables inside a service from another object

Tags: java, android, object, service, reference

I have a service that collects sensor data.
The service is started in a class, lets call it `x`. Inside `x` I've defined a few methods for a JavaScript interface in a **webview**.

now I need to get that data inside `x` to inject it to the webview to post it to server. 
what is the best practice for this?

How can I get a reference to the service instance inside `x` so I can access its methods and properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if its the best way or not, but I recently solved this problem by using the Application structure.

Create a class.

```
public class myApp extends Application {
    public int yourData;
}
```

Then use the following code to access from any Activity in your program.

```
myApp app = (myApp) getApplication();
int localVar = app.yourData;
```

Don't forget to update your Android Manifest

```
    <application
    android:name="myApp"
```

Answer (score 3):

I know two way to do it.
Declare your service as a singleton and implement methods to access your variable.

```
YourService.getInstance().getVariable();
```

But I wouldn't recommand this method.

The other way is to use binder system provide by Android.

Code in your activity.

```
private YourService yourService;
private boolean serviceBound = false;
private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName cn, IBinder ib) {
        yourService = ((YourService.ServiceBinder) ib).getInfo();
        serviceBound = true;
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName cn) {
        serviceBound = false;
    }
};
```

And then you can call methods implemented in your service on your yourService object.

You also have to implement a binder in your service like this.

```
public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {

    public YourService getInfo() {
        return YourService.this;
    }
}
```

Hope it helped.